# Unsatisfied Dependency Exception in Springboot junit test

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, junit

I am using spring-boot 1.5.9. I have created a simple spring-boot application which has the following directory structure.

[image]

`LibraryService.java` autowires the repository interface and has a method to save a book to the library.

LibraryService.java

```
@Service
public class LibraryService  {
  private static final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(LibraryService.class);       

  @Autowired
  BookRepository bookRepository;

  public void save(Book book){
    bookRepository.save(book);  
  } 

  public long count(){
    return bookRepository.count();
  }
}
```

Below is the BookRepository interface

```
public interface BookRepository extends MongoRepository<Book, String> { }
```

When I autowire the `LibraryService` in the test class, I find it is not injecting properly and I get the unsatisfied dependency exception. Following is the LibraryServiceTest class

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@DataMongoTest
public class LibraryServiceTest {

  @Autowired
  LibraryService libraryService;
    
  @Test
  public void testSave(){
    Book aBook = new Book("Harry Potter", "J. K. Rowling");
    libraryService.save(aBook); 
    assertEquals(1, libraryService.count());;
  } 
}
```

I tried the `@MockBean` instead of `@Autowired` in the test class and had no exception, but the repository instance was evaluated to null which resulted the test to fail. What is the correct way to inject the dependency when using junit?

EDIT

Following is the stack trace:

```
2017-12-31 09:48:00.112 ERROR 57648 --- [           main] 
o.s.test.context.TestContextManager      : Caught exception while allowing 
TestExecutionListener
[org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener@32464a14] to prepare test instance [com.example.demo.service.LibraryServiceTest@56193c7d]

org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.example.demo.service.LibraryServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'libraryService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.service.LibraryService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:588) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:88) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessPropertyValues(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:366) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1264) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.autowireBeanProperties(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:386) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.injectDependencies(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:118) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.support.DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:83) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.boot.test.autoconfigure.SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(SpringBootDependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.java:44) ~[spring-boot-test-autoconfigure-1.5.9.RELEASE.jar:1.5.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:230) ~[spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:228) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:287) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:289) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:247) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363) [junit-4.12.jar:4.12]
at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191) [spring-test-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:86) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:459) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:675) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:382) [.cp/:na]
at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:192) [.cp/:na]
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.example.demo.service.LibraryService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.raiseNoMatchingBeanFound(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1493) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1104) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1066) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:585) ~[spring-beans-4.3.13.RELEASE.jar:4.3.13.RELEASE]
... 29 common frames omitted
```

Comment: When you ask about an exception, always post the exact and complete exception stack trace. You should mock your DAOs to test the services. That's basically the first reason why DI is useful.

Comment: @JBNizet Hi I have added the stack trace.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/data/mongo/DataMongoTest.html):

> Annotation that can be used in combination with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` for a typical MongoDB test. Can be used when a test focuses **only** on MongoDB components.
>
> Using this annotation will disable full auto-configuration and instead apply only configuration relevant to MongoDB tests.

So, this will exclude your service from the spring context (and it should be annotated with `@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)` anyway).

Use that to test your Mongo repositories. To test your services, mock the repository (which is why DI is useful in the first place), and test the business logic inside the service on the mocked repository.

Comment: Thank you. I removed the `@DataMongoTest` annotation and it did the trick.